# Java: bidiretional composition example

Tags: java, oop

***Question:***

*Does it exist a situation (in real life) when you need to use bidirectional one-to-one composition? When?* Means A have reference to B, and B have reference to the same A object.

***Code:***

How do I figure it out:

```
public class A {

    int val;
    private B b = new B(this);

    public A() {
        this.val = 10;
    }

    public void getAVal() {
        System.out.println("A val = " + val);
    }

    public void getBVal() {
        this.b.f();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.getAVal();  // echo 10
        a.getBVal(); // echo 0
    }
}
public class B {

    private A a;
    private int val;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.val = a.val; //WRONG! A isn't constructed yet
    }

    public void f() {
        System.out.println("B val = " + this.val);
    }
}
```

***P.S.*** And if it is realy needed in some situations, please tell what proc and cons it has.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Who says they are in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is a fairly common structure, as you correctly point out there are a number of instabilities inherent, not least of which is the issue of how to tidily destroy the structure.

The commonest avoidance tactic is to wrap the two objects in a handler.

```
public class C {
  private A a;
  private B b;

  public A getA () {
    return a;
  }

  public B getB () {
    return b;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hah, it what I want to hear! please some examples with real code (means common libraries or frameworks).

Comment: @NickoleAbs - Any of the `Collection` classes stand as examples. There is *one* collection containing many related objects. The relation is not stored in the related objects, it is stored in a separate object that maintains that relation. In the case of a `LinkedList` there is usually a `Node` object that holds the relationship. In the case of an `ArrayList` there is an `Array` that maintains the relationship.

Comment: And is there any reasons to use code like mine instead of wrapper. I asking because I've hear about using code like mine in SQL cascades. What it is neccesity or a mistake?

Comment: @NickoleAbs - If the data structure is intrinsically self-referential then the implementation of the data structure is also likely to be so. Generally however, trying to make your objects *do one thing and one thing only* will move inter-object references out into separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty common case.

Imagine for instance a class `Husband` and `Wife` having a reference to each other if the couple is married.

The pros is that from or class or an other you have the reference to the other. You represent all the relationships between objects and it makes the navigation through them easier.

The cons is usually maintaining those relationships. Since every relation has two endpoints, you have to maintain both endpoint if the relation change.

A good common case where this happens is a *double* linked list, having reference to both previous and next elements.

Comment: Yes, but what about destroying? In my case I avoid that troubles because reference B is accessible only via A object. But if you realy want that relationship you need to have access to both A and B.

Comment: I agree with Nickole, a one way relationship is not a relationship, just ask all those Miley Cyrus fans.

Comment: In your example, if you cannot access A from B and thus do not take advantage of A being referenced in B, what's the point?

Comment: @Vakh, you are right. But if I add getB() and getA() methods in A & B classes appropriately, I would have some problems with destroying and maybe some other issues.

Comment: That's my cons ;-) You have to update both endpoint at the same time to avoid an *illegal* state